# C# application exit, when close not the main form with x

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application which have 2 forms, a main and an other form.
I have an exit button in the other form (when pressed Application.Exit()) but how can i call this, when somebody click the x on this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it on form closing or form closed event of your form.

Answer (score 1):

In  OtherForm.Closed(sender, e) or  OtherForm.Closing(sender, e)

```
     Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple; in Form1.cs

```
    private void CloseApplicationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 m= new Form2();

        m.X_Click(this, null);

    }
```

so in form2.cs make click event public

```
    public void X_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: This does NOT quit application when x button on Form2 is clicked.

Comment: @Sayse horrible? whats your idea?

Comment: my idea would be similar to answers already posted, not creating a global variable for a form, why on earth would you?

Comment: @Sayse you see you dont have another solution

Comment: what i would do has already been suggested as an answer so why write it again? the problem with your approach is that globals can take up space in memory for the lifetime of an application.. so thats  fine if you intend to close the application  (i suppose) but otherwise you just have a form sitting there saying "is it my turn yet?"

Comment: @Sayse if you check the code it wont be in memory life time! it will be called when user want to close application.

Comment: so why have it global at all? just instead of making a form just call application.exit as well... i think what op was asking was to access code on an already existing form too

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have both do

```
Application.Exit();
```

Unless you have some common code you want to run as part of the exiting scenario?